# Website wont show on IE once I activate scripts. Everything is missing except for the background

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, compatibility

So, I've been creating a site based off a template.  The site used to work on IE, but I'm afraid that I have made changes since then that causes everything to go haywire.  When first visiting the site my grids and alignments are all off and most of the javascript doesnt work.  When I activate scripts and ActiveX all of the elements of the site are invisible except for the background.  Though, I can still see the source in this instance.

The site (for now) is: [http://www.escroft.com/index(main).html](http://www.escroft.com/index%28main%29.html)

Answer (score 1):

If the site is not displaying when you turn scripts on, you probably have a script error.  Open your developer tools with F12, and reload the page; the console should show you what errors you have, and then you're on your way to fixing them.